# How do I hide the shadow under react-navigation headers?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How do I hide the shadow under react-navigation headers?
They look like this.
[image]

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Add the following to the navigationOptions header style.

```
const AppNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    'The First Screen!': { screen: FirstScreen },
  },
  {
    navigationOptions: {
      header: {
        style: {
          elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
          shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS
        },
      },
    },
  },
);
```

The documentation isn't great yet, but you can learn about navigationOptions in the [React Navigation Docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/navigation-options).

Comment: This gives me error: ```ExceptionsManager.js:63 Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {style}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in View (at CardStack.js:391)```

Answer (score 50):

in react navigation V5 this how you can do it:
to do it for all screens apply `screenOptions` prop to `<Stack.Navigator>`

in example:

```js
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: {
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0
          },
        }}
      />
      </Stack.Navigator>
```

to do it for a specific screen apply `options` prop to `<Stack.Screen>`

in example:

```js
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Example"
        component={ExampleComponent}
        options={{
          headerStyle: {
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0
          },
        }}
      />
```

**UPDATE V6:**

since released React Navigation V6, you can't hide header shadow using `headerStyle` option. instead of that you can use bolean option `headerShadowVisible` and set it to be `false` like example bellow:

```js
    <Stack.Screen
      name="Example"
      component={ExampleComponent}
      options={{headerShadowVisible: false}}
    />
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Comment: Even with this option there is still a slight tint of a line

Answer (score 26):

The following works for me as the original Stylesheet uses ["borderBottomWidth" on iOS](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/blob/363f93fc4d449f180dca05079b13a27c274fdd0a/src/views/Header/Header.js#L353):

```
const navigator = StackNavigator(screens, {
  navigationOptions: {
    headerStyle: {
      elevation: 0,
      shadowOpacity: 0,
      borderBottomWidth: 0,
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 20):

I don't know how much this answer will value, but sharing my code to let you know that this worked for me for **react-navigation version: 3.9.1**

```
const AppNavigation = StackNavigator(
{
  FirstScreen,
},
{
 defaultNavigationOptions: {
  headerStyle: {
    elevation: 0, //for android
    shadowOpacity: 0, //for ios
    borderBottomWidth: 0, //for ios
  },
},
})
```

Answer (score 9):

In v5 you can do the following

```js
<Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name="Example"
        component={ExampleComponent}
        options={{
          headerStyle: {
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0
          },
        }}
      />
</Stack.Navigator>
```

Comment: This is exactly right to achieve in V5 of React Navigation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8):

Good afternoon, [React Navigation 6](https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2021/08/14/react-navigation-6.0/):

```
<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShadowVisible:false}}>
```

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
      Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
      Main: { screen: MainScreen },
      Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    },
    navigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0,
        }
    }
);
```

or

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
    {
      Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
      Main: { screen: MainScreen },
      Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
    },
    header: {
        style: {
            elevation: 0, //remove shadow on Android
            shadowOpacity: 0, //remove shadow on iOS
        }
    }
);
```

Comment: @GregBenner try adding code inside components, example `Login.navigationOptions =  {
        headerStyle: {
            elevation: 0,
            shadowOpacity: 0,
        }
    }`

Comment: const stackNavigatorLoggedInConfig = {
  cardStyle: { shadowColor: 'transparent' },
  headerStyle: { height: 0, padding: '0', border: 'none' },
}

Answer (score 3):

in react-navigation version 5.x.x:

```
      <Tab.Navigator
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: colors.darkGray,
          labelStyle: { fontSize: 12 },
          style: { backgroundColor: colors.white, borderTopWidth: 0, elevation: 0, shadowOpacity: 0, },
        }}
      >
```

Answer (score 3):

it is:

```
options: {{
  headerShadowVisible: false,
}}
```

check the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator) for more info:

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/native-stack-navigator/#headershadowvisible

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Try passing `cardStyle: { shadowColor: 'transparent' }`

```
export const AppNavigator = StackNavigator(
{
  Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  Main: { screen: MainScreen },
  Profile: { screen: ProfileScreen },
},
cardStyle: { shadowColor: 'transparent' }
```

As per this question [React Navigation Stack Navigator default shadow styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43772224/react-navigation-stack-navigator-default-shadow-styling)

Comment: Thanks, I tried every flavor of changing headerStyle to no effect. This did the trick at the bottom of my stack navigator!

Answer (score 1):

I have been trying to solve this problem for the past couple of hours and have finally found the solution.
The problem in my case was that the header was in a different Z position than the rest of the other components.

try:

```
const styles = {
  headerStyle: {
    zIndex: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of 2019 this answer doesn't work in version 3.

The new way of doing it is:

```
const AppNavigation = StackNavigator(
  {
    'The First Screen!': { screen: FirstScreen },
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      headerStyle: {
        elevation: 0,
        shadowOpacity: 0,
      },
    },
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using react navigation v5, i use this code :

```
 const HomeStackScreen = ({navigation}) => (
  <HomeStack.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    headerMode="screen"
    mode="modal"
    screenOptions={{
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: COLORS.WHITE,
        elevation: 0, // remove shadow on Android
        shadowOpacity: 0, // remove shadow on iOS
        borderBottomWidth: 0,
      },
      headerTintColor: COLORS.GREY,
      headerTitleStyle: {
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat-SemiBold',
        fontWeight: '600',
        fontSize: 18,
      },
    }}>
    <HomeStack.Screen
      name="Home"
      component={Home}
      options={{
        title: 'Expanded',
        headerLeft: () => <RenderHeaderLeft />,
        headerRight: () => <RenderHeaderRight navigation={navigation} />,
        headerTitleAlign: 'left',
      }}
    />
    <HomeStack.Screen name="HomeDetails" component={HomeDetails} />
  </HomeStack.Navigator>
);
```

put shadowOpacity and elevation inside headerStyle

Answer (score 1):

As of 2023, what works for me is:

```
options={{
    headerShadowVisible: false,
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For expo route v2, it's like this:

```
<Stack.Screen
  options={{
    {...other props here}
    headerShadowVisible: false
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

The lastest version:

```
<Stack.Screen 
  options={{
    headerShadowVisible: false
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, none of the answers work. I needed to set `headerShadowVisible: false` for work:

```
      screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
        headerLeft: () => customHeaderLeft({ route, navigation }),
        headerTitleAlign: 'center',
        headerShadowVisible: false
      })}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, and it worked for me !

```
export const SignedOut = StackNavigator({
  SignIn: {
    screen: SignInScreen,
    navigationOptions: {
      title: "SignIn",
      headerStyle: {
        shadowOpacity: 0, // This is for ios
        elevation: 0 // This is for android
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The shadow is achieved via elevation, use:

```
 headerStyle: {
     backgroundColor: 'white',
     shadowColor: 'transparent',
     elevation: 0,
 },
```

Answer (score -1):

For React Native Navigation 5

```
<Stack.Screen
      name={"Profile"}
      component={Profile}
      options={{
        headerTitle: "Profile",
        headerHideShadow: true,
      }}
    />
```

Or

```
<Stack.Navigator
    screenOptions={{
      headerHideShadow: true,
    }}
  >
```