# React Navigation Stack Navigator default shadow styling

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios, react-navigation

I'm using [React Navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs) to construct a tab bar based type of an app in ReactNative.

- "react-native": "0.44.0",
- "react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.9",

I've got the navigation part pinned down and working. But with regards to styling I'm seeing a shadow on the StackNavigator (navigation controller) inside tab bar. Refer image below.

[image]

I'm not used to seeing this kind of a shadow on native iOS apps (I'm an iOS mobile dev trying out RN)

upon further investigation I saw that there are 'shadow' properties specified in ['Card.js'](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/views/Card.js) in ReactNavigation. So I manage to fixed the issue by passing in some overriding [cardStyle](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#StackNavigatorConfig) like so

> cardStyle: { shadowColor: 'transparent' }

Given all the above, I have two questions

**Question 1**
Why is this the default behaviour/styling?

To debug the issue, I decided to do a quick view debugging in Xcode and found that 'shadow' does not show up in there.
[image]

**Question 2**
Why is this happening?. Since RN app is essentially a native app (native iOS in this instance), isn't view debugging a reliable way to debug these kind of view related issues?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me. Even though this is older, we are on this older version of react-navigation and yeah not sure why this is the default values on the card. I'm assuming they fixed this in new versions